# Spark scala filter multiple rdd based on string length

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to solve one of the quiz, the question is as below,

Write the missing code in the given program to display the expected output to identify animals that have names with four

letters.

```
Output: Array((4,lion))
```

Program

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List("dog","tiger","lion","cat","spider","eagle"),2)

val b = a.keyBy(_.length)

val c = sc.parallelize(List("ant","falcon","squid"),2)

val d = c.keyBy(_.length)
```

I have tried to write code in spark shell but get stuck with syntax to add 4 RDD and applying filter.

Comment: val e = b.union(d);
e.lookup(4);

Comment: I found one more answer: b.subtractByKey(d).collect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the *PairRDD* [`lookup`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) method:

```
b.lookup(4).toArray
// res1: Array[String] = Array(lion)

d.lookup(4).toArray
// res2: Array[String] = Array()
```